# Wix: How to make conditional branch in one checkbox checked?

Tags: wix

Wix 3.10

Hello:

I'm afraid another basic question....
Is it possible making a conditional branch refering Property in Publish tag?

The window has one checkbox and two edit textboxes.
I want to make TxtX86Folder.value = "[TxtX64Folder] (x86)" when I check the X86SAMEASX64 checkbox...And I don't want to change edit value when the X86SAMEASX64 unchecked.

For example, if I set "D:\hogehoge\database" in TxtX64Folder and check the X86SAMEASX64 , I want to output "D:\hogehoge\database (x86)" in TxtX86Folder.

Any ideas?

```xml
<Wix xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi'>

    <!-- this property links to the UI SQLSvrInstanceDlg defined -->
    <Property Id="X64ROOTPATH" Secure="yes" Value="C:\Program Files\" />
    <Property Id="X86FLDSAMEASX64" Secure="yes" Value="1" />
    <Property Id="X86ROOTPATH" Secure="yes" Value="C:\Program Files (x86)\" />


  <Fragment>

    <UI>
      <Dialog Id="SQLSvrInstanceDlg"
              Title="[ProductName] [Setup]" NoMinimize="yes">

        ～Snip～

        <Control Type="Edit" Id="TxtX64Folder" X="45" Y="170" Width="220" Height="18" Property="X64ROOTPATH" Indirect="no">
        </Control>

        ～Snip～

        <!--X86 Install Folder-->

        <Control Id="X86SAMEASX64" Type="CheckBox"
                 TabSkip="no" CheckBoxValue="1" Property="X86FLDSAMEASX64" Text="Use same X64 drive(&amp;S):">
          <Publish Property="X86ROOTPATH" Value="[X64ROOTPATH]] (x86)"><![CDATA[X86SAMEASX64 = "1"]]></Publish><!--It seems I cannot write such condition in Publish tag, I simply want to show what I want to do...-->
        </Control>

        ～Snip～

        <Control Type="Edit" Id="TxtX86Folder" X="45" Y="225" Width="220" Height="18" Property="X86ROOTPATH" Indirect="no">
          <Condition Action="disable"><![CDATA[X86FLDSAMEASX64 = "1"]]></Condition>
          <Condition Action="enable"><![CDATA[X86FLDSAMEASX64 <> "1"]]></Condition>
        </Control>

        ～Snip～

      </Dialog>
    </UI>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Light command error is LGHT0204 : ICE03 by the wrong syntax above. But it seems that escaping http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/error-LGHT0204-ICE03-Invalid-format-string-when-use-quot-quot-in-value-td4763093.html doesn't solve this problem.

```xml
      <Publish Property="X86ROOTPATH" Value="[X64ROOTPATH]] (x86)"><![CDATA[[\[X86SAMEASX64[\]] = "1"]]></Publish>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry,　please forget it. Just my stupid mistake....orz. I confused property with checkbox id....

```xml
      <Publish Property="X86ROOTPATH" Value="[X64ROOTPATH] (x86)" Order="5"><![CDATA[X86FLDSAMEASX64 = "1"]]></Publish>
```

Comment: I take the consequence as my bad reputation, :( in such case, I am not sure I should delete my thread.